# Copy button created on XML programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a button on my XML and I want to create others like that one programmatically. Is there an easy way to copy the button properties instead of copying one by one?

My button:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_height"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/photo" />
```

What I would like to happen:

```
@BindView(R.id.fabImage)
FloatingActionButton fabImage;

private void addMoreButtons(){
FloatingActionButton newFab = fabImage;
myLayout.addView(newFab);
}
```

Comment: in same activity?

Comment: @EliasFazel yes

Comment: You can use `getLayoutParams()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams() depending on what you want. Everything else should be in that page of the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private Button addMoreButtons(){
    FloatingActionButton newFab = LayoutInflater
   .from(context)
   .inflate(R.layout.button, null);

    myLayout.addView(newFab);
    }
```

R.layout.button - root element must be button (fab or any other button).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse it in same activity just reuse it in a different position. once you define instance of it by finding view you can reuse.

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

now you can button so add this **`btn`** wherever you like.
for example if initially it at bottom and you want to add it on top later first you need to have **GroupView** (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout) on top and then add that button to it.

```
linearLayoutTop.addView(btn);
```